# symfony2 twig how to join string with object variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to make a connection like this:

```
{% set img_src='images/ksiazki/'~{{new_book.tytul}}~'.jpg' %}
```

But I am still getting this error:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression
>   enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `{{` and `}}` as you are already inside a twig block `{% ... %}`

Modify your code as follows

```
{% set img_src='images/ksiazki/'~ new_book.tytul ~'.jpg' %}
```